# Can we achieve compile-time type safety for a union of types we can't control?

Tags: kotlin

Let's say I have a function:

```
fun doSomething(vararg pairs: Pair<String, *>) {
    // Do things with the pairs
}
```

The problem with this approach is that it allows any type for the second half of `Pair` (e.g. `Pair<String, CustomType1>`).

What if I only want to allow a finite number of types, how would I achieve that?

If the function had a simpler signature, I could achieve the restriction via overload, like so:

```
fun doSomethingSimpler(param: Boolean) {
    // Boolean implementation
}

fun doSomethingSimpler(param: Int) {
    // Int implementation
}

// etc.
```

If the restricted type "set" was in my control, I could use an interface or a sealed class to achieve this. E.g.

```
sealed class Root
class Child1 : Root()
class Child2 : Root()

fun doSomethingICanControl(param: Root) {
    // Root implementation
}
```

Yet what if I don't have control over the types or they are primitive, how do I prevent `*` from allowing everything through?

I know I could use smart-casts to get run-time safety, but can this be done at compile time?

Or does the language disallow it?

**Edit 1**

I know I could create my own box types (e.g. `MyBoolean`) and use a common interface or sealed class, but that would be boilerplate that everyone would have to write every time they needed to.

**Edit 2**

To be clear, I'd like to be able to make an invocation like so:

```
doSomething(
    "key1" to false,
    "key2" to "value2",
    "key3" to 86
)
```

... I.e. Have a mixed set of "second" (of `Pair`) types.

Comment: Marker interface is the only way to achieve that. For class that you does not have access (e.g. int) you can box it yourself.

Comment: Self deleted my answer as edit 2 invalidates it.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? Is *doSomething* a method of a library you call? or does a library call your *doSomething*?

Comment: @D3xter A library I call, e.g. Kotson's `jsonObject()`

Answer (score 3):

So to sum it quickly up:

You want to call methods from a library that expects `Pair<String, *>`,
but limit the possible values that `*` can be.

TL;DR: What you are trying to accomplish is not possible without some kind of wrapper, because

1. We have no Sum-Types in Kotlin, so no way to tell the compiler that you expect an Int or a Double or a Float and nothing else
2. If a library-method expects something to be `Pair<String, *>`, there is no way for us to tell the compiler, that we just want to be able to give it a `String` instead of `*`

One way to get that behaviour is to create a Decorator ([Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)), e.g. create your own extension methods that allow only a subset

```
class Foo {
    //Allows everything
    fun doSomething(param: Pair<String, *>)
}

//Now lets create our own extension methods
fun Foo.doSomethingWithInt(param: Pair<String, Int>)

fun Foo.doSomethingWithBoolean(param: Pair<String, Boolean>)

fun Foo.doSomethingWithString(param: Pair<String, String>)
```

Or if you dont want to be able to call `Foo.doSomething()` you
can create a Decoractor-Class:

```
class FooDecorator {
    val foo = Foo()

    fun doSomething(param: Pair<String, Int>) { }
}
```

And the following example is not possible without some kind of Wrapper, because there are no Sum-Types in Kotlin:

```
doSomething(
    "key1" to false,
    "key2" to "value2",
    "key3" to 86
)
```

What you could do is something like:

At first, create your own `JSONItem` type and add Extension-Methods to Types that can be used as one

```
class JSONItem<T> private constructor (item: T)

fun Int.asJSONItem() = JSONItem(this)

fun String.asJSONItem() = JSONItem(this)

fun Boolean.asJSONItem() = JSONItem(this)
```

Then you are able to do something like that:

```
//Your own personal doSomething
fun doSomething(varargs: param: Pair<String, JSONItem>) { 
    //Call the real doSomething()
    doSomething(param.map { Pair(it.first, it.second.item) }}
}

doSomething(
    "key1" to false.asJSONItem(),
    "key2" to "value2".asJSONItem(),
    "key3" to 86.asJSONItem()
)
```

Comment: Your `Foo` extension overloads won't compile because you haven't annotated them with different JVM names. As for your `.asJSONItem()` approach, that's not bad. I was just wondering whether the language could handle this without repeated boilerplate and it seems like it currently cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Denotable union and intersection types are not currently supported in Kotlin (as of 1.1.x).

[This](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-13108) is the relevant issue.